# Bitmap created from raw pixel data in c# won't display in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bitmap, header, metadata

I'm extracting raw RGB pixel data from a bitmap, storing it in a byte array, and then recreating a new bitmap from that array. It works fine and the images display correctly in Chrome, Firefox, but not in IE.

I'm assuming this is because I'm not writing any headers or metadata. Paint opens the file, but not Photoshop interestingly, complains about the format saying "Could not place the document 'Image.bmp' because the file-format module cannot parse the file".

I'm not concerned about PS, but I do need them to display in IE, although it's almost certain their issues are caused by the same factor.

My question is what absent information is preventing IE from displaying my bitmaps, and how do I add it, in c#?

**Save Bitmap Function**

```
public void SaveBitmap(byte[] array, int width, int height)
{
    // Create new bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Lock the bitmap for writing
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    // Copy the RGB values into to the bitmap
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(array, 0, bmpData.Scan0, array.Length);

    // Unlock the bits and save.
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    bmp.Save("Image.bmp");
}
```

[This](http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/Image.zip) is an example image created by my code. It is in a zip file because interestingly if I upload the image to a web-server, IE **can** display it. It's as if the server performs some kind of processing on the file adding missing header information...

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use `.bmp` considering it's an almost outdated image format? Anyway check the web requests / responses and find the difference.

Comment: I rolled with bitmap because I viewed it as the easiest image format to work and learn with. The main goal is to have the user upload images in the form of raw pixel data to a sever, which is then displayed to a second user and through a WebBrowser control object, inheriting all the functionality and flaws of Internet Explorer.

Comment: The difference between the two files? That's kinda the question, what is it. I'm aware most likely it is a missing or incomplete header, but I'm unsure how to access those meaningfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Image.Save(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=vs.110).aspx) saves the image as PNG, so you have created a PNG image with a BMP filename extension. Use [`Image.Save(string, ImageFormat)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) to specify the format like so:

```
bmp.Save("Image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```